# Facebook sharing won't pull through ANY images anymore,

Tags: wordpress, facebook, addthis, sharing

I have created a company blog and have begun implementing various social sharing plugins, had a look at integrating with OG and now Facebook won't pull any images when the page is shared.

The debugger tool says that it can find a suitable image (the featured image for each post) and when I share the same link to LinkedIn the images pull fine.

I can't work out for the life of me what might be wrong, again it's not that Facebook isn't pulling the right image... it's not pulling ANY.

Does anyone have experience with this/know what might be wrong?

http://www.chapman-freeborn.com/en/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are your saving your files?

See below

> Facebook does not like .png files so if you’re saving
>   your images in that format and experiencing this issue, try changing
>   your images to .jpg or .gif format.
>
> One of the main issues with images not displaying on Facebook is the
>   file path that they are located at. Facebook does not like spaces in
>   the name of an image or in the name of a folder that an image is in.
>   Facebook also doesn’t like when there is extra “stuff” added to the
>   end of an image URL such as image dimensions.

**Source (with further info):** http://ansonalex.com/troubleshooting/fix-articles-linked-on-facebook-dont-display-thumbnails-images/

Comment: I have tried various different file formats and none seem to work, it's not to do with how they are saved as it used to pull through the industry logos at the bottom of our site if no featured image was found, now it doesn't pull anything.